# How do I break out of a loop while reading in a string?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, java.util.scanner

For example:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  
int counter=1;
while (!(keyboard.equals('0')))
{
    for (int i=1;i<=counter;i++)
    {
        prodNum[i]=keyboard.nextInt();
        quantity[i]= keyboard.nextInt();
    }   
    counter++;
}
```

How do I break out of a loop when I enter in a zero? I can't seem to figure it out. It keeps taking input, even when I enter a zero? I need for it keep taking input until the user enters a zero.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A tip: Print what `keyboard` is using a `System.out.println()´;` And you will most likely see what the problem is. If you don't want to do that think what `Scanner` is and what `0` is. And how they compare to each other.

Answer (score 1):

`keyboard.equals('0')` will compile, but it is never going to evaluate to `true`, because `Scanner` object cannot possibly be equal to a `Character` object.

If you would like to wait for the scanner to return zero to you, you should call `next()` or `nextLine()` on it, and compare the resultant `String` object to `"0"`.

```
while (true) {
    while (keyboard.hasNext() && !keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer value.");
        keyboard.nextLine();
    }
    if (!keyboard.hasNextInt())
        break;
    prodNum[i]=keyboard.nextInt();
    if (prodNum[i] == 0)
        break;
    while (keyboard.hasNext() && !keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer value.");
        keyboard.nextLine();
    }
    if (!keyboard.hasNextInt())
        break;
    quantity[i]=keyboard.nextInt();
    if (quantity[i] == 0)
        break;
    i++;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/2PRqWL)

Comment: Now it's giving an "unreachable statement" error after the break loop.

Comment: @KyleButler That's strange. Are you sure you copied it from the answer, and did not insert an extra semicolon after an `if`?

Comment: yes, I copied and no I did not insert a semicolon after if.

Comment: @KyleButler It should definitely compile. I fixed the logic a little to let you process end-of-input gracefully, too. Please see the demo link.

Comment: @KyleButler You are welcome! Please try the code out, and if it works, consider accepting the answer to let other site visitors know that you are no longer actively looking for an improved solution, and earn yourself a new badge on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int counter=1;
    int flag = 1; 
    while (flag != 0)
    {
        for (int i=1;i<=counter;i++)
        {
            if(flag == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            prodNum[i]=keyboard.nextInt();

            quantity[i]= keyboard.nextInt();

            flag = quantity[i];

        }   
        counter++;
    }
```